# rollback a previous commit, but still maintain history

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the following history in git

```
A-B-C-D-E-F
```

I want to rollback the changes that I did in commit E, but wanted the changes that I in commit F. So I did a `git rebase` like this

```
git rebase -i D
```

and picked only commit F and ignored commit E. My history now looks like

```
A-B-C-D-F
```

But, what I want to do is, rollback the changes done in commit E, but still maintain in history that E was added and then removed. Something like this

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-E1
```

Where E1 is a commit which reverts the changes done by commit E.

How to do it in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git revert $SHA_FOR_E` will make a new commit "the opposite of" commit E.

[From the man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html):

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them.

Comment: Thanks. I read about `revert`, but some how got confused with `rebase`

Answer (score 2):

You use the [revert command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html).  This creates a commit that it is the inverse of the SHA provided.

`git revert <SHA E>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `rebase` would be the way to go.  My first suggestion would be to use [revert](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)

```
git revert E
```

This will create a new commit reverting that E was applied

Another option would be to just reverse the patch.

```
git show E | patch -R -p1 && git commit .
```

will reverse what was done in `E`.